# Statistical pre-checks on transaction data (real estate)

Tags: time-series, least-squares, autocorrelation, stationarity, diagnostic

I'm currently working on a paper in the field of real estate. As it's been some time since my last quant finance class, I just wanted to cross check my understanding of the problem at hand.

The data contains a large number of real estate transactions, each with transaction date, price, and ca. 30 attributes of the housing unit (sqm, rooms, coordinates, year of completion etc.).

When using OLS for time series, I'd normally assume to test for homoscedasticity, autocorrelation, multicollinearity and stationarity. Yet the data sample does not present a conventional time series, as it's random transactions. Am I right or am I missing something here?

This might sound like a real no brainer, but I couldn't an exact answer. Academic papers with similar data don't seem to test for all of the above, most of them merely test multicollinearity, omitted variable bias and spatial dependence via Moran's I.

Edit: based on the regression, the goal will be to create a price index for housing. In that sense the coefficients of the time dummies will be sorted by time.

Comment: Transaction *data* or *date*? Also, if your data is not a time series, testing for autocorrelation might not be a good idea; see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310561/durbinwatsontest-in-r-for-non-time-series-data/310603#310603) recent thread. Moreover, formal testing of multicollinearity is also not a good idea, but this is perhaps more of a curiosity; see Dave Giles blog post ["Can You Actually TEST for Multicollinearity?"](http://davegiles.blogspot.be/2013/06/can-you-actually-test-for.html).

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy it's transaction dates, so when each housing unit was sold. Sorry for the typo. So I'm guessing it's not really a time series then?