# I ran the durbinWatsonTest() in R and got p-value=0 for non time series data. Is this possible?

Tags: p-value

I used `durbinWatsonTest()` on a non-time-series dataset:

```
durbinWatsonTest(automobileRegression)
```

And the following is the result I get:

```
lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value
  1       0.3437134      1.309245       0
Alternative hypothesis: rho != 0
```

Is that possible to get the p value=0?  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give the whole example that can be reproduced? Also, if a function you are using isn't in base R, it helps to tell us what package it is found in.

Comment: The example has bunch of data in it and I don't know how to upload the data here.  But I used "car" library to use the function.  I am not familiar with R so please give me any advice

Comment: I used the Auto.csv located in [link](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/data.html).  Then, Auto = Auto[1:8] and automobileRegression = lm(mpg~., data=Auto) to get the regression object

Comment: P-values being reported as 0 is typically just a matter of some rounding convention.

Comment: The implicit question about what the D-W test means is addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310561/durbinwatsontest-in-r-for-non-time-series-data/310603#310603.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: yes, it's possible.

Long answer: The Durbin Watson test is about the correlation of the residuals. If the data are ordered in some way, you'll get a significant DW test.

Here's an example:

```
> library(car)
> data(cars)
> fit1 <- lm(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars))
> car::durbinWatsonTest(fit1)
 lag Autocorrelation D-W Statistic p-value
   1       0.3729415       1.19495   0.004
 Alternative hypothesis: rho != 0
```

My DW test is significant.

Look at the data:

```
> head(cars, 12)
   speed dist
1      4    2
2      4   10
3      7    4
4      7   22
5      8   16
6      9   10
7     10   18
8     10   26
9     10   34
10    11   17
11    11   28
12    12   14
9     10   34
```

It appears that the data are sorted in order of speed. This makes the residuals autocorrelated and so the DW test is significant.

Let's put the data into a random order:

```
set.seed(1234)
cars <- cars[order(runif(nrow(cars))), ]
```

Fit the model, and do the test again:

```
fit2 <- lm(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars))
car::durbinWatsonTest(fit2)
```

DW test is no longer significant. The test depends on the order of your data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  But you have 0.004 not exactly 0.  I got exactly 0 and I wonder this is problem in the function.

Comment: No: dwt(lm(lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars[order(resid(fit2)), ])))

Comment: Careful analysis, but the take-home message is, I suggest, that the test is utterly meaningless unless the order is that of time.

Comment: @NickCox makes the crucial point, much more succinctly than me. :)