# R - is it ok to treat autocorrelation by randomly changing the order of variable

Tags: r, multiple-regression, autocorrelation, random-generation, durbin-watson-test

I'm working on a multivariate linear regression. I performed a Durbin-Watson test to test for auto-correlation and found it in my model (p-value <0.05 of Durbin Watson test). I then randomly changed the order of the row of the dataframe with the following R-command: `df=df[sample(1:nrow(df))]`. I re-ran the auto-correlation test and found p-value of around 0.5. It sounds too easy to be true but did I remove the auto-correlation? If not: 1. why? and 2. how should I proceed?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Durbin-Watson only makes sense if you have time series data or some equivalent. If you do, then shuffling the data can't solve any problem. Otherwise the order of observations in your dataset is immaterial in most regression problems. For much more, see other threads such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310561/durbinwatsontest-in-r-for-non-time-series-data It's surprising, or rather dismaying, that any software would produce a Durbin-Watson test unless the dataset has been declared as time series data in whatever is the approved manner.

Comment: Calling a regression _multivariate_ is good use of terms if and only if your response variable is multivariate. Otherwise, even the term _multiple_ is dispensable.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326305/i-ran-the-durbinwatsontest-in-r-and-got-p-value-0-for-non-time-series-data-is could also be relevant.

Comment: Thank you very much @Nick Cox! As i have a model of the form `blood pressure ~ bodyMassIndex + exercise`, I consider that it is not a time series or equivalent and for this reason will not look for auto-correlation (will not perform the Durbin-Watson test).

Comment: If data points are different people, that would appear to be the case.